# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite looping

Tags: iis-7.5, rewrite, subdomain

I have a webapp that is located in /subdir1/subdir2/ I'd like to simplify it for the users by adding a subdomain sub.domain.com but it keeps looping.  I'd tried to add additional rules to prevent it but no joy.

So what happens is http://sub.domain.com/subdir1/subdir2/subdir1/subdir2/subdir1/subdir2/subdir1/subdir2/subdir1/subdir2/subdir1/subdir2/

My rule in web.config:

```
<rule name="subdomain" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(?!sub/)(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="sub.domain.com/subdir1/subdir2/" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="sub.domain.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="subdir1/subdir2/" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
So what i'm really trying to do is make it easier for the users.  Right now they have to type www.domain.com/subdir1/subdir2/ to access the login page for the product.  What I wanted to do was create a single subdomain that would rewrite to the above link.  Rather than typing the long url just go to sub.domain.com and it would redirect or rewrite to the www.domain.com/subdir1/subdir2/ location.  I hope that makes my desire a bit more clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`{HTTP_HOST}` represents only the host part of a URI:

`http://[HTTP_HOST]/subdir/index.html`.

Thus, your first condition is irrelevant (it will never evaluate false).

What you want is `{PATH_INFO}`:

```
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/subdir1/subdir2" negate="true" />
```

Effectively saying: "If this part of the URL: `http://sub.domain.com[PATH_INFO]` starts with "/subdir1/subdir2", don't rewrite

If you want `/additional/path/to/content.html` rewritten to `/subdir1/subdir2/additional/path/to/content.html`, you'll need a [back-reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules) to the match as well:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="subdir1/subdir2/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

Comment: Sounds correct but didn't fix it.  Tried playing with the pattern too.  Leading / ending / ^ no ^, still the same behavior.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help without knowing what you expect and what actually happens, but I've updated my answer on intuition

Comment: Updated my post to hopefully be a bit clearer.  Thanks for the help.